# downloading images using javascript from a single Chrome tab

Tags: javascript, image, download

i came across this script on the web:

```
javascript:(function(){function I(u){var t=u.split('.'),e=t[t.length-1].toLowerCase();return {gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1,png:1,mng:1}[e]}function hE(s){return s.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/"/g,'&quot;');}var q,h,i,z=open().document;z.write('<p>Images linked to by '+hE(location.href)+':</p><hr>');for(i=0;q=document.links[i];++i){h=q.href;if(h&&I(h))z.write('<p>'+q.innerHTML+' ('+hE(h)+')<br><img src="'+hE(h)+'">');}z.close();})()
```

And it fairly opens up all the images of a tab whose address bar you run the script in, in a new tab.
But that new tab, opens up as an `about:blank` tab, and when i press Ctrl+S to download the page, and hence thereby getting all the images opened in that tab, what i hope would happen doesn't.

Ctrl+S doesn't work on `about:blank`, and i kinda hoped there would be some way to download those images opened in this kind of tab. How do i do this? Is there any way in JavaScript to achieve this?

i searched around the web, and found `wget`, but i didn't really get it. Is there any easier way altogether to just download images from a tab using javascript?

Comment: Your scripts just opens a popup and lists the images there. What do you want? A download dialogue for each image? A one-click-download-all application? Opening all images in a new tab each that you can Ctrl+S them?

Comment: when the images are opened in the single tab, i want to save them all from there, to a directory. Usually, like on a normal page, if Ctrl+S it, then the page is saved, and the folder which stores it contents - css, js, images etc - will be of interest to me. But i its not happening with `about:blank`

Comment: You can't. There are some APIs for that, but file system access is usually denied for JS in web browsers.

Comment: well i do need to build a solution. If not js, then what else could help me do that? I can program in Python, C, C++ and Java. But i most likely program in Python.

Comment: You could develop your own [Chrome extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html). You can also use JS for that, and you will have access to the basic internal methods.